# Extending functionality of the existing ATG CRS Store

Tags: atg, configurable-product

There is a requirement wherein we need to extend the existing ATG CRS functionality. We need to implement the configurable product functionality. Whatever research we have done till now says that there is no form handler in ATG CRS to take care of this. Can someone provide a lead on how to go about coding for the Java Class and related components for this.

I am totally new to ATG and all that I have at my disposal is the entire CRS module, but it looks vast. 
Please help.

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to ATG, good starting point would be working patiently through the documentation available from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/index.html

Configurable products/configurable SKUs are non-trivial customizations and does require solid understanding of the framework. It takes much more that just a formhandler, I am afraid.